# How to get the distance and the angle (distance and bearing) from a depth camera

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, pointcloud, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using deep learning to detect an object and after I got the detection work, I made boxes around this object and I calculated the mid point of the box. Now I want to measure the distance and the angle between the camera and the mid point of the box around the object. I manged to get the coordinates of the mid point x,y in a frame but still don't know to calculate the distance and bearing. Thanks for advance.
ps: I am using realsense camera D435.

Jad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300639/how-to-get-the-distance-and-the-angle-(distance-and-bearing)-from-a-depth-camera/) by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2018-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to find this information with a tangent function. With the pose of the camera and pose of the box in some global, identical frame (could even be camera frame) you can use the change in Y and change in X to pull out the azimuth angle if you're looking for 2D. You can use the change in Z as well to pull out azimuth and elevation angles.

It sounds like you already have distance, so that's a good start!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on 2018-08-16**:
Thanks ! . Yes I got the distance so now I can measure the distance but need to figure out how to get the angle. I will try to apply  what you have said. :)

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-08-16**:
Awesome, can you mark the answer as correct then to close it out for maintainers?

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-08-05**:
@Jad,
hi, would you please share your code with me as wwll? i have the same problem, get the distance and bearing of the nearest object